# Every button clears fileupload field C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

All I've done so far on my C# .net Web Form is add a FileUpload object and a button. Neither have any code behind them. Once I choose a file, the name is displayed in the FileUpload field like it is supposed to, but any button I add clears the field when it is clicked!

Answer (score 0):

Set the fileupload to autopostback="true"?